# Accessing file in UWP throws UnauthorizedAccessException even with access granted

Tags: c#, uwp, filesystems

I'm trying to browse files and send them to a service, and for that I'm making a small internal utility app in UWP.

I made a POC console application and everything works fine.

Now I'm in an UWP app and I get an `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when executing the same code.

I must add, the exception comes from a package I'm using (but I'm not developing), I'm assuming since it works in the console app and not the UWP app, the error is from my end, still, here is the complete error message :

```
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Access to the path 'D:\pulseinvoices\uk_00003.pdf' is denied.
```

I have authorized the app in the filesystem privacy settings
[image]

And I have done the same in the manifest :

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
 
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

...

  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

I've read somewhere that setting the file as an environment variable is also necessary. This would completely defeat the purpose of file picking (if users are required to set an environment variable every time they need to pick a file, that's just not practical), but hey, I'm open to suggestions, so I also did this :

[image]

For the sake of being as complete as possible, here is the code that I'm executing :

```
private static readonly string FILE = @"D:\pulseinvoices\uk_00003.pdf";  //Test document

await service.ProcessAndWait(FILE, channel, params);
```

I'm lost because the console app works fine, executing this code only fails in the UWP app.

**important** : The `service` object is coming from an external .dll, as I said earlier in the post. I'm still hoping the issue is coming from my end so I can fix it. So I have the path using `StorageFile`, but when that .dll is trying to access it, I get the exception. That .dll is in my solution, so it should have the same access rights as the solution, correct?

Everything is hardcoded, this is pretty much a one-liner app at this stage. The only difference is that it's running in UWP vs Console.

What are my options?

EDIT : Adding some more details for clarity.

Here is how I fetch the file in the first place, before using the external .dll to process it.

[image]

Behind `selectFile`, a custom object is created with the path of the file among other things, so I do have a `StorageFile` object that is usable within my UWP app at that point. It's only once I use that external .dll and with `file.Path` that it fails. If I don't use the storage file at all and just hardcode the path I have the same exception. My solution can access the file, but the .dll within that solution cannot ?

Answer (score 1):

Even when you declare the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, you still can't access the files through non-UWP APIs. Instead, you have to use the `StorageFile` API:

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
```

If you want to interop with non-UWP APIs, you can work with the `Stream` of the file. Add `using System.IO;` to the top of your file and then to read:

```
var stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

Or to write:

```
var stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
```

Comment: Hello Martin ! Thanks for the answer. I'm already getting the file using the StorageFile API. That works, and I can see it's path. Then, when I use that path with the code shown at the top I get the exception. 

I hope this helps clarify the context of my problem. I do have the file at one point, it's when I use that .dll asking for a path that it fails. I tried the real path with StorageFile or hardcoded it, to no avail. Do you need more information to help me ? It seems like a really simple issue that I just don't have the knowledge of (yet) and I've ran out of things to try

Comment: I added an edit at the end and also another part in the middle flagged as "important", maybe that will be even clearer

Comment: Unfortunately the service is most likely not using `StorageFile` to access the file, so there is the issue. Your option would be some other overload of `ProcessAndWait` which accepts a `Stream` instead, or you need to copy the file into `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`, which is then accessible even using non-UWP file APIs

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this unexpected behavior should be the same as @Martin Zikmund said. When you declare the broadFileSystemAccess capability, you have to use the StorageFile API to access the files.

The issue is that what API the `service` object is using in the DLL. It's highly possible that the DLL is using some desktop API to access the file instead of using StorageFile API. That will cause the issue.

Comment: So, considering I **must** use that DLL and can't change the API its using, what are my options?

Comment: @GilSand If you must use that DLL, then you might need to use it in a WPF or Winforms project because desktop apps have more file permissions than the UWP project had.